# Word Macro replace hard returns in heading with soft return will change header style type

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have an interesting issue with my Word Macro.  I have code to look for the Heading 1 style and replace the hard return with a soft return.  (This is so when I do up the table of contents it'll be formatted with the story title and then the author all on one line.)

This is my code thus far:

```
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1")
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "^p"
    .Replacement.Text = "^l"       
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
```

This works as it should, but it also changes my Heading 1 to a Heading 2 style.  (Apparently this is how Word works)

I'm looking for ideas on how I can do the replace AND keep it as Heading 1?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but it seems to me you should be able to specify the .Replacement.Style = "Heading 1" and that would be applied as part of the Execute...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple replace-all won't do in this case. One solution would be to search for the relevant places in your document, replace the paragraphs with manual line breaks one-by-one and the restore the desired formatting. This can be done using the following macro:

```
Dim nextParagraphRange As Range

With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1")
    .Text = "^p"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False

    Do While .Execute(Replace:=wdReplaceNone)

        ' check whether there is another paragraph
        ' following the "Heading 1" paragraph
        Set nextParagraphRange = Selection.Range.Next(wdParagraph)
        If Not nextParagraphRange Is Nothing Then
            ' check if the following paragraph is a "Heading 2"
            If nextParagraphRange.Style = "Heading 2" Then

                ' replace paragraph mark with manual line break
                Selection.Range.Text = Chr(11)

                ' restore original "Heading 1" style so that the
                ' paragraph still is level-1 in the ToC
                Selection.ParagraphFormat.Style = "Heading 1"

                ' move the Selection to the text that before was "Heading 2"
                Selection.Move wdCharacter
                Selection.MoveEnd wdParagraph
                Selection.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1 ' don't include the paragraph mark

                ' re-apply "Heading 2" as direct formatting
                Selection.Style = "Heading 2"
            End If
        End If

    Loop
End With
```

Comment: @JenniferMacDonald: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Glad you got your problem solved. You can help everyone if you upvote useful answers and mark the answer that solved your problem as the accepted answer. Thanks.

Comment: Oops, I just found a minor issue.  This appears to only to do the replacement for the first one found.  I set up a breakpoint in the While loop and it does only do it the once.

Comment: @JenniferMacDonald: Depending on your actual document you might need to move the selection at the end of the loop body behind the paragraph, e.g. using `Selection.Move wdParagraph`.